# Getting the red underline on view names when using custom methods in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, resharper

I have a lot of extension methods/helper classes for ASP MVC that take in controller names, action names, or view names as parameters(much like the default HtmlHelper methods). Visual Studio usually underlines these names with a straight red line to indicate that they match a valid controller/action/view when you use one of the built in MVC methods. Is there a way to get this same support for my own methods? It's a nice little feature, but that feature slowly disappears when I stop using built in methods.

Quick example: This will have a straight red line underneath the "SomeViewName" string if that view is known to exist, otherwise the string itself becomes red colored.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return View("SomeViewName");
}
```

And this would be an example of one of my own methods(which is in a separate library from MVC site project itself)

```
// Example action using method
public ActionResult Show(int id) 
{
    return ViewOrNotFound("Show", id);
}

// Example of the method itself
private ActionResult ViewOrNotFound(string viewName, int id) 
{
    var model = DoSomethingToGetModel();
    if (model != null)
    {
        return new ViewResult { ViewName = viewName };
    }
    else 
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us example of your own methods you are talking about? Which files do you have and where they are in the source tree? Are they in the same namespace as your application?

Comment: Are you using resharper? This sounds resharper-y...

Comment: @Rikon: You're right, seems to be a Resharper feature. I didn't even think to check that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently all you need to do is use JetBrains Annotations since this is a ReSharper feature.

```
public void SomeHelper(this HtmlHelper,[AspMvcController] string controller, [AspMvcAction] string Action, [AspMvcView] string viewName)
{
}
```

Comment: Note - I had to install the NuGet "ReSharper Annotations Default Implementation" package first, and add the JetBrains.Annotations namespace in my class. But this definitely works. Thanks!